# Почему функция shell_exec не работает?

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

В php почему-то у меня не работает функция shell_exec для собственно ручных bash скриптов.
Например я написал bash скрипт /sbin/mybashscript и содержание банальное:

```
#!/bin/bash echo Hello World!
```

Этот скрипт выводит текст *Hello World!*, при вводе в терминал

```
#mybashscript
```

или же

```
#/sbin/mybashscript
```

То все работает, нужный текст выводит. Когда же я в php (php как модуль apache, на сайте) напишу var_dump(shell_exec('mybashscript')); выводит NULL, и любая другая функция типа exec, system и т.п.
Если напишу системную команду типа var_dump(shell_exec('date')); все выводит, или если напишу var_dump(shell_exec('/etc/init.d/apache2 reload')); тоже работает, ну по крайней мере выводит текст.

Версия php 5.3. Safe mode отключен, функции shell_exec и т.п. соответственно разрешены.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указывать путь к файлу:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('/path/to/mybashscript'));
var_dump(shell_exec('./mybashscript'));
```

Comment: я это хотел написать, что я и с полным путем пробовал, в общем так тоже не работает.

Comment: В любом случае в stderr должна выводится ошибка. Можете еще так сделать:

    var_dump(shell_exec("./mybashscript 2>&1"));

Comment: ответ

    string(30) "sh: ./mybashscript: not found "

куда копать?

Comment: при указании полного пути пишет:

    string(39) "/bin/sh: Can't open /sbin/mybashscript "

почему он в первом случае не может найти его? а во втором вообще не может открыть?
права на файл стоят 777

Comment: В первом случае текущая папка отличается от той, в которой лежит запущенный php-скрипт (вероятно вам поможет php-функция chdir(...)). Во втором случае недостаточно прав - для того чтобы баш мог выполнить ваш скрипт(mybashscript) у него должны быть права на чтение и выполнение (права 111 - только выполнение). Для того чтобы скрипт запустился установите хотя бы права 555.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам стоит попробовать PHP CLI.

А если уж без bash вам не обойтись, используйте хотя бы chroot.

Comment: А можно подробнее? Что за chroot и чем оно поможет?

Answer (score -1):

Все, я разобрался, надо было просто sudo перед командой ставить.

Comment: Вот уж не самый лучший выбор, измените права у скрипта на 555 и будет все запускаться.

Comment: Да просто внутри скрипта еще много команд, не буду же я на системные ставить везде права 555.

Comment: А sudo дает слишком обширные права, что может стать потенциальной уязвимостью в безопастности. В обычном случае у скрипта бы не хватило записать в системный фаил, а с правами админа ей вероятно это удастся. Так что решайте сами что вам важнее 5 минут гемора с установокой прав или день два на поиск причины почему вашу систему взломали.

Comment: Если я, например, поставлю 555 на команду reboot, то уязвимость в любом случае будет, что с sudo, что с правами на выполнение.
Эти баш скрипты используются только определенным виртуальным хостом в апаче, другие пользователи просто не смогут ничего выполнить вообще и записать-удалить вне своей домашней директории.

Comment: От того, что Вы добавите для reboot права на чтение плюс к правам на выполнение **уязвимость системы не изменится.** Действия reboot (и других "системных" команд) определяются правами лица, запустившего ее.

Дело в том, что права, указанные для файла (программы) не влияют (кроме случая s-бита) на права, которыми обладает программа для ее действий. Допустимые действия программы над файлами определяются **сопоставлением UID и GID лица, запустившего программу** с правами доступа к файлу для владельца файла, группы и прочих. 

Подробнее читайте в документации по *nix.

Comment: у меня все запускается от одного пользователя, тем самым собственно и добавляется уязвимость